# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на input сохранялась форма и сразу же запускалась функция из вьюхи?

Tags: python, django

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на input сохранялась форма и сразу же запускалась функция из вьюхи?

**Шаблон**

```
       <form method="post" action="">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="options-wrapper">
            <h4>Действия</h4>
            <div class="options-action">
              <label class="checkbox-img" >
                {{ form.liking }}<span></span>
              </label>


              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.following }}<span></span>
              </label>

              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.unfollowing }}<span></span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <h4>Способ продвижения</h4>
            <div class="options-action">
              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.hashtag }}<span></span>
              </label>

              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.competitors }}<span></span>
              </label>
            </div>


            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
              </div>
              {{ form.competitors_list }}
            </div>
              <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-success start mt-3" value="Запустить" id="start"
                     {% if flag %}
                     disabled="disabled"
                      {% endif %}>


          </div>
          </form>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def settings(request):
    account = InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user)
    temp = SettingAcc.objects.filter(account=InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user))
    try:
        if temp.count() == 0:
            flag = True
            form = FormSettingAcc(request.POST or None)
            if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
                new_form = form.save()
                new_form.account = InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user)
                new_form.save()
        else:
            flag = False
            source = SettingAcc.objects.get(account=InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user))
            form = FormSettingAcc(request.POST or None, instance=source)
            if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
                form.save()
    except:
        error_message = 'Ошибка при обновлении настроек бота'
        print(error_message)
    return render(request, 'primeApp/settings.html', locals())


@login_required
def start(request):
    print('def start()')
    account = InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user)
    action.delay(account.login_inst, account.password_inst)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

Comment: думаю что для этого нужно писать некий код

Comment: Как минимум надо класс с обработкой формы. Погуглите про ModelForm. Статей на тему обработки форм в Django много.